# django-mssql - Invalid connection string attribute

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-mssql

This is the error I am getting when I run the django web server.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
 Server', u'Invalid connection string attribute', None, 0, -2147217843), None), u'Error opening connection: DATA SOURCE=
server1;Initial Catalog=Misc;UID=DOMAIN\\dcullen;PWD=******;PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;MARS Connection=True')
```

**settings.py**

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'Misc',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'server1',
        'USER': 'DOMAIN\\dcullen',
        'PASSWORD': 'PWD',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
            'use_legacy_date_fields': 'True'
        }
    }
}
...
```

[connection-strings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/) seems to indicate that the driver is not for SQL Server 2012 but `SQL Server 2000`.

**Python version:** 2.7
**Django version:** 1.7.11
**django-mssql version:** 1.7

**Package homepage**: https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer now, I was using the wrong `provider`.

Changing to `Provider=SQLNCLI11` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try these settings. Hope this helps

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '1433',
         'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB', #SQLNCLI11 , SQLOLEDB
            'use_legacy_date_fields': 'True',
            #'extra_params' : 'DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True',
            #'connect_timeout': 0
            }
    }
}
```